# regular expression: extract last 2 characters

Tags: regex

what is the best way to extract last 2 characters of a string using regular expression.

For example, I want to extract state code from the following

"A_IL"

I want to extract IL as string..

please provide me C# code on how to get it..

```
string fullexpression = "A_IL";
string StateCode = some regular expression code....
```

thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use regex instead of common string manipulation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the regex:

```
 ..$
```

This will return provide the two characters next to the end anchor.

Since you're using C#, this would be simpler and probably faster:

```
string fullexpression = "A_IL";
string StateCode = fullexpression.Substring(fullexpression.Length - 2);
```

Comment: You don't actually need the leading `.*`

Comment: Yeah, and I realized you don't need the group for most engines either.

Answer (score 4):

Use `/(..)$/`, then pull group 1 (`.groups(1)`, `$1`, `\1`, etc.).

Comment: Far too complicated, Keep it simple.

Comment: "Complicated" depends on your definition of Simple. In many scenarios this is far simpler and elegant. For example, this could change a 2-3-step operation into a one-step transformation.

Answer (score 0):

as for the best way, I'd say it's  `.{2}$`
it is more elegant and self-descriptive.