# Regex get last two digits of year

Tags: regex

I must use regex in order to get the last two digits of a year but only when 4 digits exist. I have the following regex which works perfectly when there is 4 digits.  Example 2014 - 14

```
^.{2}
```

However I need this to only work when 4 digits are present. I'm having an issue with it emptying my string when only 2 digits exist.

Comment: Try `..$`

Looks to be a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511588/regular-expression-extract-last-2-character"s

Comment: @HunterBrown can you use that with a not? I'm finding my pattern is replacing the last two now rather than keeping them. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply match the four digits and capture only the last two.

```
^\d{2}(\d{2})$
```

Then reference capturing group `#1` to access your match result.

Comment: wow... I don't understand why I complicated myself with something so easy as you did lol. +1 since this is the simpliest answer. Btw, I think you should add `^` at the beginning since yours can match 123456

Comment: So quick question, I just realized my pattern is matching on the last two which is correct, but then it replaces them. I really need to keep the last two at all times. Any thoughts.

Comment: Java, I have this. @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "(\\d{2})\\d{2}$"),
                    @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = ""),
                    @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all")}),

Comment: This is what I'm using http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceFilterFactory.html I'm just trying to add the last two digits of a year to my index.

Comment: What should I be using in the pattern?

Comment: According to that link, `<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^\d{2}(\d{2})$" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>`

Comment: Yay! It worked. Could you explain to me what you just did so that I understand it for the future. Thank you so much.

Comment: The pattern matches from the start of the string to the end matching only 4 digits and captures only the last two. `$1` references what was captured in the grouping `( )` to put in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex.

```
^(?(?=\d{4}$)..(\d{2}))$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM5mO6/2)**

This regex uses an **IF** clause, so if the string is 4 digits then captures the last two.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The regex you have there shouldn't be working with 4 digits either. Your regex is looking for any 2 characters at the beginning of the string.

Try this:

```
(?<=\d\d)\d\d$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0wcfww1CmVi8cXqa)

This is different from Fede's answer in that you don't need to use and subsequently refer to a capturing group later. Only the last 2 digits are part of the match. It relies on a positive lookbehind.