# How to Automatically Format User Input 4 digits to last 2 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the credit card expiring text field that user able to type in 4 digit but i want to automatically format user input 4 digits to last  2 digits.

So, if user input 2022, i want automatically changed to last two digits "22".
I have try the maxlength 2 in html input but that doesn't work out for me.

This is try format the input 4 digits to 2 digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex get last two digits of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609821/regex-get-last-two-digits-of-year)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? What you're asking for is rather simple: a search on StackOverflow should give you the solution you need.

Comment: This sounds like very bad UX. You should make it clear that you want two digits for month and two digits for the year. Everything else will probably just confuse people.

Comment: @LucaKiebel just wanted the from the year input.. User input 2022, wanted to changed to last two digits 22. hope this help.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, I am telling you that that's probably not the best way to solve the "problem".

Comment: this is the input field <input type="text" name="expiry_year_2" id="expiry_year_2" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="yy" class="expiry_year" autocomplete="off">

Comment: I want to find the way, when user type in 4 digits of the year. See i can take out the first two digits of that input.

Comment: @Luca,, i am asking what is the solution for what i wanted to do. I do see your point but just wanted to get the fix what i have on now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check the link in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110324/how-to-automatically-format-user-input-4-digits-to-last-2-digits#comment96963463_55110324) comment!

Comment: @Olafant what link are you referring to?

Comment: [Regex get last two digits of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609821/regex-get-last-two-digits-of-year)

Comment: Thanks for the point, i saw the solution and that wasn't what i looking for. If you review the post, i am not looking to use regen for that little piece. See if there solution like jqury masking and html or css solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't believe that it's a good choice to let the user write a full year and show only the last 2 digits, you could try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/804bwsLy/10/) and/or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/804bwsLy/11/).

```
<input id="year" data-fullyear="" placeholder="yyyy" maxlength="4">

$("#year")
  .on("blur",e=>{
        let $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    let value = $this.val();
    if(value.length===4){
        $this.data("fullyear",value)
        $this.val(value.substring(2));
    }else{
        $this.data("fullyear","")
        $this.val("");
    }
  })
  .on("focus",e=>{
    let $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    let value = $this.val();
    if(value.length===2){
        let fullYear = $this.data("fullyear");
        $this.val(fullYear);
    }else{
        $this.val("");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const year = 2023

function formatYear(year) {
  const yearToArr = String(year)
  return `${yearToArr[2]}${yearToArr[3]}`
}

console.log(formatYear(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is `slice`, it can help you slice a string using two parameters. First, the starting index and second ending index. I have added some extra features too. Hope the code below helps:

```js
const lastToDigets = str =>{
    let total = ""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage=  ''
    if (str != null && str != "") {
        error = false
        if (str.length <=4) {
            total = str.slice(str.length-2, str.length)
        } else {
           error = true
           errorMessage = `The maxium length can be 4 you have given ${str.length}` 
           return errorMessage
        }
    } else {
        error  = true
        errorMessage = "Please fill the str perimeter."
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}


// Calling Function
// Answer
console.log(lastToDigets("2022"))
// Extra Feature: If the user enters a greater than length, it will raise an error
console.log(lastToDigets("12345"))
```